# JS scroll and click

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element that displays additional products. Looks like this:

```
<span class="load-products btn btn-default unveil-button">Další produkty</span>
```

I need to press this element when I reach the bottom window. Similar to infinity Scroll. I have a function that indicates window movement. I can't figure out a function that presses the span element.

https://446042.myshoptet.com/blahoprani/

Comment: Is it a browser extension? How do you handle scroll now?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pagination-loader').click();
```

Solved

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IntersectionObserver`
Also, performance tip: avoid using classes for single elements like `load-products`

```js
// options
const options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}


// define the observed object
const target = document.querySelector('.load-products');

// what to do when the object intersects the viewport
const callback = (entries) => {
    // only listen to `intersection` events
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting){
         document.getElementsByClassName('load-products')[0].click()
    }
}


const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(target);
```